# Neo4j Cannot find Long value

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using Neo4j 2.3.3 and SDN 4.1.1

When I save node with long value.
(ex: memberNo : 6267057069360176000)
and findByMemberNo in browser.

```
Match (n:Member{memberNo:6267057069360176000}) Return n
```

this query can not found anything.
when I changed memberNo to String.

```
Match (n:Member{memberNo:'6267057069360176000'}) Return n
```

It can find.

Is it bug or something wrong in my code?

Comment: How many members do you have?!

Comment: @AntP under 10000, if small value(like 46938586) it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

*All fields convertible to a String using the Spring conversion services will be stored as a string.  Spring Data Neo4j includes default type converters that deal with the following types*:

*`java.math.BigInteger` to a String property*

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/programming-model/node-entities.adoc#property-optional-annotation-for-property-fields

Comment: you mean If using Long type, memberNo:'6267057069360176000' will be work?
    
only working on String type in entity class.